# User ID encoding on the URL?

Tags: screen-scraping, url-encoding

I would like to get some information from the user profiles of a certain domain.

```
www.domain.com/profiles/[userID]
```

The main problem is that the user ID is like:

```
4fc34f1ad3d85a000300b5a4
4fc34f1ad3d85a000300b5a4 
4f4bdd96848740000300026a
4f09884f9cc1590001019c98
4f1bcd5f33aa850001011811
4faa2801c619ad0003011c7e
4e4f506ac9d69600010010ca
```

so if I wnat the user profile of a certain user I have to put

```
www.domain.com/profiles/4fc34f1ad3d85a000300b5a4
www.domain.com/profiles/4f4bdd96848740000300026a
www.domain.com/profiles/4f09884f9cc1590001019c98
www.domain.com/profiles/4f1bcd5f33aa850001011811
www.domain.com/profiles/4faa2801c619ad0003011c7e
www.domain.com/profiles/4e4f506ac9d69600010010ca
```

What kind of ID is that? How I know the subjacent canonical order?

Other times was a lot easier because the user ID only was integers.

```
www.domain.com/profiles/1
www.domain.com/profiles/2
www.domain.com/profiles/3
www.domain.com/profiles/4
www.domain.com/profiles/5
```

I would like to know if this is some kind of encoding or what.

What kind of ID on the URL is that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. Maybe it's just a random string. Maybe it's a hash of something. Maybe it's specifically made so it's hard to guess the ids. Who knows?

Comment: If I have the input before the hash function of some hashes,,,

    word1 -> 4fc34f1ad3d85a000300b5a4
    word2 -> 4f1bcd5f33aa850001011811
    word3 -> 4faa2801c619ad0003011c7e
    .
    .
    .
    wordN -> 4f04efa0900aab0003006b13
Is there any way to do reverse engineering?

Comment: You cannot reverse hashes. If you know or guess the hashing algorithm though, you could simply iterate through "word1", "word2" etc. and simply hash them for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an MD5 hash. So either it's a random hash, or it might a hash of the previously used ID, or something completely different. Either way apart from brute force guessing, there's no simple way to decode them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Does not look like MD5 to me, the length does not match and the values aren't distributed well (all start with 4, most with 4f, all contain a block of 3 zeroes etc).

Comment: if you need more... 4fc34f1ad3d85a000300b5a4
4f4bdd96848740000300026a
4f09884f9cc1590001019c98
4f1bcd5f33aa850001011811
4faa2801c619ad0003011c7e
4e4f506ac9d69600010010ca
4f299a9c0810ee000100e846
4e538eb5a8f6a7000100c2a7
4f04efa0900aab0003006b13
4f04efa0900aab0003006b13
4f299a9c0810ee000100e846
4e5505577a27bd0001013063
4f2445b9d58a250001014621
4fba7705b760500003031c11

Comment: Yes it's not a MD5 hash it doesn't match the length.

Comment: Actually there's an easy way to decode an md5 hash. By googling it.

Answer (score 0):

These ID's use hexadecimal - notice there are no letters above 'f'.

The similarities between ID's are interesting - could you provide the ID's of some consecutively created pages, to check if there is a pattern to how the ID changes.

Or the website may just generate a random number between certain limits and convert to hex.